# How to read return code of command when piped with another command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script where I execute a command and `tee` to a file.
On checking the return code, it is always `0` which is for the `tee <>` command.

```
make all | tee output.log
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Make failed"
    exit 1
else
    blah blah
fi
```

Is there a way to check the return code of the first command (i.e.  `make all` in this case)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have the commands pipe `command1 | command2`, you can get each command exit code by:

```sh
echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} - ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if make all | tee output.log
then
  echo Could not write create output.log
  exit 2
elif (( ${PIPESTATUS[0]} > 0 ))
then
  echo Make failed
  exit 1
else
  echo Looks great
  ...
fi
```